# Alert! Root Drive Does Not Exist After Elementary Installation

Tags: boot, partition, grub2, uefi, elementary-os

recently I installed Elementary OS with no problems. When I started up the new OS I received this error message

```
Alert! /dev/disk/by-uuid/....../ does not exist. Dropping to the shell
```

Afterwards I ran a boot repair from a Live USB. But did not clear error

```
Boot Info Script cfd9efe + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 26Apr2016]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (3.61-4.03) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1 
__________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi
```

[boot report pastebin link](http://paste2.org/XImInPLI)

I have also tried to install mint and received the same error. I am trying to run one OS and not dual booting.

Edit: the uuid on the partition and the warning match

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring /dev/disk-by-id etc, to the /dev/sda or /dev/sdb according to the disk your system is installed, i know the first notation is better but sometimes it is broken here, i made a little distro for the company and having this problem in some random dimensions...